# EntityQuery for anonymous user

Tags: 8, entities

In my application I have a page that shows a view and a few fields from a node related to the view; this node is created when an authorized user accesses the page for the first time. When the node is published, the page can be viewed by anonymous users also.

Therefore, when the page is accessed, I have the following possibilities:

1. Authorized user and the node does not exist: create the node, then display the page in edit mode.
2. Authorized user and the node exists: display the page in edit mode.
3. Anonymous or unauthorized user: display the page in view mode.

Therefore, the first thing I have to do is search for the node with an entityQuery. My code goes like this:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node') ;
$query->condition('type', 'my_custom_type') ;
$query->condition('my_custom_field', $value) ;
$ids = $query->execute() ;
```

This works fine for authenticated users, but always returns zero records for an anonymous user, even if they have the permission to access the node (through the 'access content' permission). I googled something and I found [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57561240/drupal-7-query-custom-content-type-with-no-results) (but please note I am on Drupal 8, not 7), so I added the following before executing the query:

```
$query->addMetadata('account', user_load(1)) ;
```

This works, but seems to me more a nasty workaround than a proper solution... is it really the way to go? I looked in the permissione list to see if the anonymous user is missing some permission, but didn't find anything.

Comment: you must have some other permission/access checking on your site as `but always returns zero records for an anonymous user, even if they have the permission to access the node (through the 'access content' permission).` isn't correct for a standard drupal install.

Comment: In Drupal 8 you can use `$query->accessCheck(FALSE)`. But I agree with @Leigh, as long as the nodes are published, anonymous users should have access to the nodes in a standard install.

Comment: I should have probably mentioned that I am also using the Group module, but of course I enabled the 'view content' permission for the type I am querying.